# Centos Static DNS with static IP is not working

Tags: domain-name-system, centos

I tried to set up an CentOS7-Server with static IP-adresses and DNS-servers.
The problem so far, is, that the Domain-Name-Service is not working properly.

```
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=static
IPADDR=***.***.***.49
NETMASK=255.255.255.240
NM_CONTROLLED=no
DEFROUTE=yes
PEERDNS=no
PEERROUTES=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_PEERDNS=yes
IPV6_PEERROUTES=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
NAME=enp4s0f0
UUID=*******************************
DEVICE=enp4s0f0
ONBOOT=yes
DNS1=***.***.22.60
DNS2=***.***.56.60
```

The IP-address is created and the name-servers are "ping-able", but the DNS is not working. 
The resolv.conf automatically gets the following input:

```
DNS1=***.***.22.60
DNS2=***.***.56.60
```

Does someone have an idea how it comes to that problem.

(Its a clean CentOS7 installation with a GUI, nothing else has been installed or configured.)

thanks in advance

most sincerely

Twinhand

Comment: Do DNS lookups work if you query those servers directly?  Try `dig @***.***.22.60 serverfault.com` to test this. (Using the actual IP address.)  Does the `DNS1=...` part appear literally in your `/etc/resolv.conf` file?

Comment: Thanks for the fast respond. So, if I do dig "at"***.***.22.60, it finds something.Thanks for the fast respond. So, if I do dig "at"***.***.22.60, it finds something. If I try to use dig "at"serverfault.com it get the following response "dig "at"serverfault.com
dig: couldn't get address for 'serverfault.com': not found
" And yes DNS1= is literally appearing in the resolv.conf

Comment: OK, it seems like I found my problem. if I delete the option "PEERDNS=yes". The system is writing the name-servers correctly (nameserver ***.***.***.***) to the resolv.conf and the DNS is working properly. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

OK, it seems like I found my problem. if I delete the option "PEERDNS=yes". The system is writing the name-servers correctly (nameserver ..***.***) to the resolv.conf and the DNS is working properly. Thanks for your help.